# LINQKit predicate for code first

Tags: c#-4.0, ef-code-first, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I have read this (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Here is my code :

```
var predicateOuter = PredicateBuilder.True<T_Users>();
predicateOuter.And(d => d.code== 357);
var count=tService.GetCount(predicateOuter.Expand());
```

my service in code first:

```
public int GetCountSearch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
{
    return _entities.Count(exp);
}
```

all record in `T_Users`: 6548

all record where `code==357` : 26

But it always returns all records. but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the results of `Add`:

```
// Assign result here to predicateOuter -
predicateOuter = predicateOuter.And(d => d.code== 357);

// This should now function properly
var count = tService.GetCount(predicateOuter.Expand());
```

`Add` doesn't modify the predicate, but rather returns a new one with the additional criteria.